# Reverse range implementation

Tags: haskell

For the record, I'm a Haskell noob. I'm trying to understand why a range can be declared as

```
[1..10] -- yields [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and not

```
[10..1] -- yields []
```

It seems simple enough to implement it like this:

```
(.:.) :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]
(.:.) a b =
   | a == b = []
   | a > b = a : (a - 1) .:. b
   | a < b = a : (a + 1) .:. b
```

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `[10,9..1]` instead of `[10..1]`

`[10..1]` desugars to [**`enumFromTo`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=enumFromTo)

`[10,9..1]` desugars to [**`enumFromThenTo`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=enumFromThenTo)

**Observe how the functions behave in GHCI:**

```
Prelude> [10..1]
[]
Prelude> [10,9..1]
[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
Prelude> :t enumFromTo
enumFromTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]
Prelude> :t enumFromThenTo
enumFromThenTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> a -> [a]
Prelude> enumFromTo 10 1
[]
Prelude> :t enumFromThenTo 10 9 1
[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

The new behavior that you implemented in `(.:.)` will rarely be a desirable default, as lists generated this way can no longer **always** be assumed to be in *ascending* order. Hence the necessity to make your *descending* intention explicit with `[x,(pred x)..y]` or `enumFromThenTo`.

Comment: You have lived up to your username. Was my implementation correct though?

Comment: @dopatraman You can compare it to the current [GHC implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Enum.html#enumFromThenTo). Your implementation allows for the parameters to be inverted and still produce an intuitively populated, non-empty list. However some people might expect that `[a..b]` where `a > b` to produce the empty set `[]` given that `a` and `b` are of a well-ordered type (`Ord`) and the implicit assumption of the list syntax is that the list is to be ascending.

Comment: @dopatraman If you want to test certain properties of the `(.:.)` function, I recommend implementing a [**`QuickCheck`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) property. Examples: `propA x y = x <= y && (.:.) x y == [x..y]`. `PropB x y = x > y && (.:.) x y == [x,(x-1)..y]`

Answer (score 6):

Almost always when you have an expression like `[1..n]`, and `n` happens to be 0, you want the value to be `[]` rather than `[1,0]`. For example consider

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

Then we want

```
factorial 0  ~~>  product [1..0]  ~~>  product []  ~~>  1   -- correct
```

not

```
factorial 0  ~~>  product [1..0]  ~~>  product [1,0]  ~~>  0   -- oops
```

That's why `[m..n]` does not produce a descending list when `m > n`.

(If `m >= n+2` (for example if in `[1..n]`, `n` is negative) then it's quite likely an error condition and arguably `[m..n]` ought to be an error; but it's still defined by the language standard to be `[]`.)

Comment: You articulated he default behavior far better then my brief comment. Nice Examples!